# Which modulation technique is better for long distance transmission, if I'm using the CC1101?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

I'm using the Texas Instrument transceiver cc1101 at 430-440 [MHz] and I'm wondering what the best modulation technique is for long distance transmission.
This transceiver offers several modulation schemes:
2-FSK
4-FSK
GFSK
MSK
ASK
Ook

What should I pay attention to if I want to use the best one to transmit for at least 5 [Km]?

Extra information:

I am using a power amplifier to achieve increased transmission distance, I also know that a lot falls into the aspect of using directional antennas and other factors such as direct line of sight. Knowing this, I want to know if what I should focus on to achieve my goal is the BER of these techniques or something else.

Comment: Distance doesn't matter; desired data rate, acceptable error probability and SNR at the receiver matter. So, you'll need to supply us with a bit more info! (I'm assuming here that your channel really is a directive link with a high-gain antenna at each end – if you have multiple propagation paths, things get more complicated, and your CC1101 might not be able to equalize the resulting signal at all)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your answer, I'm just trying to understand if any modulation technique can improve my communication link regardless of the physical aspects that may be involved in the Friis equation. Is there any demodulation technique that is better than assuming that the other factors are acceptable?
If so, what would be the argument?
Would it be correct to think that the digital modulation technique that has better BER performance has therefore greater immunity to noise and is ultimately the best?

Comment: no, not regardless of physics. It's not possible to assume there's a generally better modulation scheme. You **will** have to model your channel!